# custom wp_dropdown_categories items in wordpress

Tags: search, dropdown

I have the wp_dropdown_categories function in my searchform.php file. Right now it lets the user choose what post category they want to search in.

Is there a way I can get the drop down to include a custom taxonomy and a custom post type?

For example if I have a custom post type for galleries, and a custom taxonomy for places... how can I display a wp-dropdown that lets the user choose to search either "photos" or "locations"?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send the desired taxonomies as an argument to the function. This is untested, but should work:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => array(
        'galleries',
        'places'
    )
);
echo wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

For your reference, the function `wp_dropdown_categories` is defined in "wp-includes/category-template.php" on line 301. Take a look at it as it will help you understand what you can send as arguments for the function.